# Visual Studio 2022 - Out-of-process load and evaluation

Tags: visual-studio-2022

The Preview version of Visual Studio 2022 had a feature called `Allow out-of-process load and evaluation` under `Preview Features` which no longer appears in the Current release of Visual Studio 2022.

This feature improved the load times of my solution drastically and was really useful.

Did they choose to remove this feature? I can't seem to find it anymore.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is still available albeit in the preview version of VS 2022 17.4 Preview 1 in the Enterprise Edition since that is what I am using.

I have not installed the Community or Professional Preview Versions.